# what's the purpose of an IP Gateway?

Tags: ip, gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between “default gateway” and “preferred DNS server”?](https://superuser.com/questions/77914/whats-the-difference-between-default-gateway-and-preferred-dns-server)

My hosting provider gives me an `IP` and an `IP gateway` address. I configured my domain to use the IP. I don't understand what is the use case for the gateway.

Comment: How do you plan to reach machines with IP addresses not inside your segment?

Comment: I don't think all hosting providers are explicit about it. I'm wondering when would I actually need this to mess around with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gateway is the "next hop" - basically, your PC connects to the gateway IP to get out onto the rest of the internet.

Comment: As a note, it does not actually have to connect to the internet, it could be any network (even one that is totally internal).